# I can't see specific buttons and texts In mySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, workbench, invisible

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRAVP.png)

As you can see in image,

i can't even create table because I can't see table name area and apply button

I want to know how to solve this problem

I tried to switch dark mode to light mode, but failed it.